# ngrx change detection strategy on dummy components

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular2-changedetection

I'm having a look to the example-app defined in the ngrx repo:
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app

I can see that the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` property is set only on "container" components while dummy components don't override the default change detection strategy.

Can anyone explain the reason? I would expect all the components in the application to use  `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Thanks,

Gab

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no need to set `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` on every component as setting it on a parent component disables checking for the entire branch.

```
comp1 (ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush)
   comp2        <--- won't be checked
     comp3      <--- won't be checked
```

For more information on `ChangeDetectionStrategy`, read:

- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)
- [If you think `ngDoCheck` means your component is being checked — read this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5)

Comment: Does that also mean child components inherit this strategy? Or do they still have the default strategy?

Comment: @S.Robijns, they have their default strategy, it's just that Change Detection doesn't reach them because of the parent componetn